# Get jQuery Datepicker element in a dynamic form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a dynamic form, and its has some date field which is bind with date picker and it works fine.

Once document is loaded, I would like to get all the date picker element which is bind. I don't have common class field or type for this. any way we can get all the elements which are bind with date time using jQuery?

To be more clear, I am injecting a script via a product to a site, so it can be any site, so I need a generic way to identify the datetime in that particular form.

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried?

Comment: Show the code and we will show you how to get the elements the date pickers are bound to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to get all elements that are using the DatePicker, just tag each element that uses it with a `data-*` attribute. So, when you create your input that will have the DatePicker, create it this way: `<input data-date="true"/>` or `<input data-type="date"/>`

You can then pull them from the DOM with jQuery:

```
$('input[data-type="date"]')
```

You can also do the same thing by adding a class to each element: `<input class="hasDatePicker"/>` and pull them with: `$('.hasDatePicker')`

I prefer the `data-*`, though.

Comment: To be more clear, I am injecting a script via a product to a site, so it can be any site, so i need a generic way to identify the datetime in that particular form.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI datepicker automatically adds class named `hasDatepicker`. You can use that to identify which inputs have datepicker.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js#L138